# Error in Atlassian Connect Hello World example

Tags: maven, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am trying to get Atlassian Connect working.
However I am facing with following issue:

When I run the command to start JIRA in OnDemand mode, I am faced with following error:

```
Executing: "c:\atlassian-plugin-sdk\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin\mvn.bat" com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-plugin:5.0.3:run-standalone -gs c:\atlassian-plugin-sdk\apache-maven-3.2.1/conf/settings.xml -Dproduct=jira -Dproduct.version=6.3-OD-07-013 -Dbundled.plugins=com.atlassian.plugins:atlassian-connect-plugin:1.1.0-beta.5,com.atlassian.jwt:jwt-plugin:1.1.0,com.atlassian.bundles:json-schema-validator-atlassian-bundle:1.0.4,com.atlassian.upm:atlassian-universal-plugin-manager-plugin:2.16.5,com.atlassian.webhooks:atlassian-webhooks-plugin:1.0.6 -Djvmargs=-Datlassian.upm.on.demand=true
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-amps-plugin:5.0.3:run-standalone (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/servletapi/servletapi/2.3/servletapi-2.3.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/servletapi/servletapi/2.3/servletapi-2.3.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/commons-io/commons-io/1.2/commons-io-1.2.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/1.2/commons-io-1.2.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.17/plexus-utils-3.0.17.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.17/plexus-utils-3.0.17.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.5/plexus-utils-1.5.5.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.5/plexus-utils-1.5.5.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-classworlds/2.4/plexus-classworlds-2.4.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-classworlds/2.4/plexus-classworlds-2.4.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.1/plexus-utils-2.1.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.1/plexus-utils-2.1.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.8/plexus-utils-3.0.8.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.8/plexus-utils-3.0.8.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.4.1/plexus-utils-1.4.1.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.4.1/plexus-utils-1.4.1.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-classworlds/1.2-alpha-6/plexus-classworlds-1.2-alpha-6.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-classworlds/1.2-alpha-6/plexus-classworlds-1.2-alpha-6.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.3/plexus-utils-1.3.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.3/plexus-utils-1.3.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-9/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-9/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-api/1.0-alpha-16/plexus-component-api-1.0-alpha-16.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-api/1.0-alpha-16/plexus-component-api-1.0-alpha-16.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.0.4/plexus-utils-1.0.4.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.0.4/plexus-utils-1.0.4.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-8/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-8.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-8/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-8.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/apache/maven/maven-repository-metadata/2.0/maven-repository-metadata-2.0.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-repository-metadata/2.0/maven-repository-metadata-2.0.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.4.9/plexus-utils-1.4.9.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.4.9/plexus-utils-1.4.9.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.3/commons-logging-1.0.3.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.3/commons-logging-1.0.3.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.6/commons-beanutils-1.6.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.6/commons-beanutils-1.6.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0/commons-logging-1.0.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0/commons-logging-1.0.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/commons-collections/commons-collections/2.1/commons-collections-2.1.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/2.1/commons-collections-2.1.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/xml-apis/xml-apis/2.0.2/xml-apis-2.0.2.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/xml-apis/xml-apis/2.0.2/xml-apis-2.0.2.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.0.4/plexus-utils-2.0.4.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.0.4/plexus-utils-2.0.4.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/commons-io/commons-io/2.0/commons-io-2.0.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.0/commons-io-2.0.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/commons-collections-3.2.1.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/asm/asm-all/20070324/asm-all-20070324.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/asm/asm-all/20070324/asm-all-20070324.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/com/google/guava/guava/r06/guava-r06.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/r06/guava-r06.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-7/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-7.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-container-default/1.0-alpha-7/plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-7.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.1/jsr311-api-1.1.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/ws/rs/jsr311-api/1.1/jsr311-api-1.1.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.1/jackson-core-asl-1.7.1.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.7.1/jackson-core-asl-1.7.1.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.7.1/jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.1.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.7.1/jackson-mapper-asl-1.7.1.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-jaxrs/1.7.1/jackson-jaxrs-1.7.1.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-jaxrs/1.7.1/jackson-jaxrs-1.7.1.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-xc/1.7.1/jackson-xc-1.7.1.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-xc/1.7.1/jackson-xc-1.7.1.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/commons-io/commons-io/2.2/commons-io-2.2.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.2/commons-io-2.2.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.8/slf4j-api-1.5.8.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.8/slf4j-api-1.5.8.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.3/commons-codec-1.3.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.3/commons-codec-1.3.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.6/slf4j-api-1.5.6.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.6/slf4j-api-1.5.6.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/com/atlassian/plugins/rest/atlassian-rest-common/2.9.2-m01/atlassian-rest-common-2.9.2-m01.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/atlassian/plugins/rest/atlassian-rest-common/2.9.2-m01/atlassian-rest-common-2.9.2-m01.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.5/commons-lang-2.5.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.5/commons-lang-2.5.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/com/sun/jersey/contribs/wadl-resourcedoc-doclet/1.8-atlassian-8/wadl-resourcedoc-doclet-1.8-atlassian-8.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/contribs/wadl-resourcedoc-doclet/1.8-atlassian-8/wadl-resourcedoc-doclet-1.8-atlassian-8.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2/jaxb-api-2.2.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2/jaxb-api-2.2.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2.1/jaxb-api-2.2.1.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2.1/jaxb-api-2.2.1.pom

Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2.1/jaxb-api-2.2.1.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/1.4/commons-io-1.4.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/apache/ant/ant/1.8.2/ant-1.8.2.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/ant/1.8.2/ant-1.8.2.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/junit/junit/4.8.2/junit-4.8.2.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.8.2/junit-4.8.2.pom

Downloading: https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/slf4j-api-1.6.1.pom

Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/slf4j-api-1.6.1.pom

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.948 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-08T09:44:38+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/114M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-plugin:5.0.3:run-standalone (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of goal com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-plugin:5.0.3:run-standalone failed: Plugin com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-plugin:5.0.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-plugin:jar:5.0.3 -> com.atlassian.core:atlassian-core:jar:4.0 -> com.atlassian.profiling:atlassian-profiling:jar:1.3 -> servletapi:servletapi:jar:2.3: Failed to read artifact descriptor for servletapi:servletapi:jar:2.3: Could not transfer artifact servletapi:servletapi:pom:2.3 from/to atlassian-public (https://maven.atlassian.com/repository/public): maven.atlassian.com: Unknown host maven.atlassian.com -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

It gives an error of unknown host.

What does this error mean? I am using a username and password to access Internet on my PC. Is it due to the same?

Answer (score 0):

If you are behind a proxy you have to configure proxy settings in your `~/.m2/settings.xml` please check [Maven - Guide to using proxies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)